# Unable to reference a environment variable inside our Site Address property inside a cloud flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, powerapp, power-platform

We have a solution with 2 environment variables:

- One which reference a SharePoint site
- The other reference a SharePoint list

[image]

Now when we created a new cloud flow inside our solution >> we are not able to reference the above environment variables:

We expected to get a link to Add a custom item as follow:

[image]

But we got this:

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Click on drop down arrow against site address property
2. Use "Enter custom value" option at the end of the options menu opened after clicking the dropdown - this option is same as "Add a custom item" option.

[image: Flow Image]

---

**OR**

Enable experimental features in Power automate settings.

You will be able to see "Add a custom item" option" (similar UI as given in your question) after enabling experimental features.

Follow below article for detailed steps to enabling external features in Power automate.

**Reference**: [How to Turn on Experimental Features in Power Automate](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/11/how-to-turn-on-experimental-features-in-power-automate/)